# Oreilly servlet String Value manupulation

Tags: string, servlets, jspx

I am trying to truncate a string using  Oreilly servlet classes.

My problem is that I don't want to use the whole string but a part of it. **paramPart.getStringValue()**
will give the value uncut but I have a scenario which requires I get a part of the string. 
for example: The String value could be **"xxxyyyy ,,,"** while I only require to work with **"xxxyyyy"**. I hope my problem is clear to that point.. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Pss

Am using com.oreilly.servlet classes on my jsp application.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem which worked just fine, using java's substring() method.

first I got the value by String value = paramPart.getStringValue();
then I went ahead and created another variable  String  valuetrucated =  value.substring(0, value.length() - 2);

this will truncate the string value to the 3rd char from the end of the string...